# kmeans clustering 2D matrices

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-computing, k-means

I am trying to cluster images represented by 28x28 matrices of values <0;1>. These matrices are originally stored in a list. However `kmeans` doesn't accept input list so I tried to make a 3D array of `length(mylist)x28x28` size. `kmeans` now clusters single values in each matrix, not the matrices themselves. How would I accomplish matrix clustering?

Small code example:

```
m1 <- array(rep(runif(64, 0.0, 1.0),64),dim=c(8,8))
m2 <- array(rep(runif(64, 0.0, 1.0),64),dim=c(8,8))
m3 <- array(rep(runif(64, 0.0, 1.0),64),dim=c(8,8))
list1 <- list(m1,m2,m3)

# This doesn't work
clusters <- kmeans(list1, 2)

# Transform to 3D array
library(abind)
array1 <- do.call(abind, c(list1, along = 0))

# This doesn't cluster matrices, but their elements
clusters <- kmeans(array1, 2)
```

Comment: What is `m1`? is it an image?

Comment: According to `?kmeans`, the function will only accept matrices. In order to perform this comparison, you will probably have to construct a matrix from your data. Two ideas: 1. transform each matrix into a vector and `rbind` them. Then feed this to `kmeans`. 2. find a specific function that maps images stored in the manner you describe to a single dimensional vector, use that and then `rbind`.

Comment: @Headpoint it is basically the matrix returned by `imageData(readImage(img))`  and yes it can be displayed.

Comment: What does clustering images mean to you? Are you aware of kmeans' clustering criterion? And how does this one work out for matrices?

Comment: @ayshelina, in that case they should be in rows - each image is an observation/sample - if you are trying to cluster the images into groups.

Comment: @lmo thank you, I followed your advice and it works. I find it a bit ugly to transform each 2D array into 1D, do `kmeans` and then transform the results back to 2D to display them etc. Anyway I guess that is the only way :)